# Download audio file using sftp in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, sftp

What I am trying to do is click a link and when I do, it connects to my server and downloads the audio file available from the browser. I was able to connect to my server and download the .wav file. But when I try to open the audio files with windows media player I get a error:

`Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.`.

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

    var config = {
        host: 'someHost',
        port: '22',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'root'            
    }
    var fileName = "hello.wav"; //File Name
    // Connect to server
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
        // Get the file as a readable stream
        sftp.get(fileName).then((data) => {
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            // Set headers to download file 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/audio/wav');
            // pipe stream 
            data.pipe(res);
        });
    });
});
```

The files are playable before getting stored in the server or are playable when downloaded by external application like WinSCP. But I am not sure what is going on with the CODEC when downloaded through the ssh2-sftp-client module.

**Solution**

I figured out there was some issue with the encoding type. Inside the ssh2-sftp-client module specifies what type of compression and encoding is believable to change `sftp.get(remoteFilePath, [useCompression], [encoding]);`. So I  changed the compression to false because it defaults to true and the encoding value to `null` because it defaults to `utf8`.

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

    var config = {
        host: 'someHost',
        port: '22',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'root'            
    }
    var fileName = "hello.wav"; //File Name
    // Connect to server
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
        // Get the file as a readable stream
        sftp.get(fileName, "false", null).then((data) => {
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            // Set headers to download file 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/audio/wav');
            // pipe stream 
            data.pipe(res);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the MIME type should just be `audio/wav`.

Comment: I tried changing the discrete type to `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/wav');` but still no luck.

Comment: Maybe `audio/x-wav` ? What is the client side code you're using to play the file ?

Comment: I tried that too as well as `audio/x-pn-wav` and `audio/wave` but it still did not work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types). I am using windows media player to play the audio file.